# In which R package can I find the function expandDates

Tags: r, date, datetime, package

I have received some software in R to run which calls on many Packages/Libraries not specified in the code.
I have been tracking down the functions one by one in various packages but cannot find one function:

expandDates

I tried packages like Chron or other time/date processing packages with no luck from:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html

The call looks like this:

```
tte_increm <- expandDates(start_date = start_date, end_date = end_date)$time.days[['numTotDays']]/365
start_date <- '2017-09-01'
end_date <- '2018-12-31'
```

Help, please!

Comment: If this is in a script you hold, do `getAnywhere(expandDates)` or `methods(expandDates)` and you may get where it's from.(may need to use quotes in those calls, not sure)

Comment: Thank you but no luck. The function isn't anywhere in the loaded code or Libraries. I did try though. The syntax is:

Comment: Hard to tell, could you link to a GitHub gist or repo of the code?

Comment: Thank you but no luck. The function isn't anywhere in the loaded code or Libraries. I did try though. The syntax is: getAnywhere("format.dist") and methods(summary) but I also tried with and without quotes.

Comment: The code actually comes from GitHub: https://github.com/andrepoorman/PFE

Comment: Searching the [code](https://github.com/andrepoorman/PFE/search?q=expandDates&unscoped_q=expandDates) shows no instance of the function.

Comment: The function is on row 44 of the routine helpers.r